# Unable to uninstall SQL Server 2017 from an inherited work PC

Tags: sql-server, windows-10

I've got an inherited work PC that has SQL Server 2017 installed locally.  The company is no longer on that version so I want to remove it, however, when I go to add/remove programs and try to uninstall it I get a popup that says:

*This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action.  Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the default app settings page.*

Anyone have any thoughts as to what the default app for uninstalling SQL Server should be?  Or what file type it's referring to?  I've never seen add/remove programs pop this message up before.  The machine is Windows 10.

EDIT: I should note I am the admin of this machine.

Comment: If I got a used PC, the first thing that I would do is reformat the drive, deleting everything, and reinstall the OS. Why don't you do this? It would remove any and all cruft that the previous user left there. Also, this question is a better fit for Super User than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Fair enough, if someone can vote to move it i would appreciate it.